# Order of keys in RestEasy MultipartFormDataOutput

Tags: java, multipartform-data, quarkus, resteasy

I'm trying to send a document to a remote API with **RestEasy** on **Quarkus**.

The API I'm calling requires me to send a `multipart/form-data` body with 3 files. Problem is, the API cares about the order in which they are specified and will return an error if they are in the wrong order.

The problem seems similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69227680/missing-part-in-multipartformdataoutput-depending-on-order-of-keys), but the problem there concerns a server *returning* data, while my problem concerns a client *sending* data. I posted a comment anyway and will delete this question if something resolutive comes up there.

The parameters are called `PARAMETERS`, `INDEX` and `DATA` and need to be specified in this exact order and intentionally uppercased. I'm using a [MultipartFormDataOutput](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-beta-4/javadocs/index.html?org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/providers/multipart/MultipartFormDataOutput.html) to store the files to send and as the other question suggests, it might be a problem with the keys being ordered alphabetically.

This is the service interface I'm using:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "api-url")
public interface DocuService {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    @Path("/send_document")
    String sendDocument(
            @MultipartForm MultipartFormDataOutput data
    );

}
```

While this is how I add the files to the payload and send it:

```
MultipartFormDataOutput mpFormData = new MultipartFormDataOutput();
mpFormData.addFormData("PARAMETERS", requestData.getParamFile(), new MediaType("application", "xml"), "parametersFile.xml");
mpFormData.addFormData("INDEX", requestData.getIndexFile(), new MediaType("application", "xml"), "indexFile.xml");
mpFormData.addFormData("DATA", requestData.getDataFile(), new MediaType("application", "json"), "dataFile.json");
docuService.sendDocument(
        mpFormData
);
```

I can't find a way to specify the key order, or maybe a similar object that will allow me to do so. Maybe someone can help me shed some light on this.

Thanks in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: It does look like the backing map is a `HashMap` so order is not guaranteed. A change to the implementation would be required to get this to work. One option might be to extend it and change the `MultipartFormDataOutput.getFormDataMap()` to return a `LinkedHashMap` instead. Or actually, you'd want to set the protected field in the subclass.

Comment: Interesting point, the object actually already instantiates a LinkedHashMap. I will look in to it, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately don't have enough rep to add to the comment thread, so going to use an Answer.

I had used that approach of extending MultipartFormDataOutput and using a linked hashmap. Unfortunately in resteasy reactive 3.x MultipartFormDataOutput was made final, so that workaround no longer works, so in case that was your solution beware of  that.

As of now I don't know of a substitute.